# Regex - returning a match without a period

Tags: regex

I'm using the below regex string to match the word "kohls" which is located in a group of other words.

```
\W*((?i)kohls(?-i))\W*
```

It works great when the word is alone, but if the word is in a url, the match includes a period on both sides.

See the below examples:

`Thank you for shopping at Kohls` - returns a match for kohls.

`https://www.kohls.com` - returns a match for **.kohls.**

**Edit. https://www.KohlsAndMichaels.com - doesn't return any match for kohls.**

I want it to only extract the exact match for kohls *without* periods or any other symbols/text in front or behind it. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution to this question?

Comment: Yes, actually I am. It seems it is more difficult to pull text from the middle of a word or string. I also want it to be case insensitive. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In cases like that you can always use a site like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), which explains the regular expression and shows the matches with colors. So this is how your regular expression currently works:

[image]

As you can see in **blue** color, the problem with the dots is in the `\W*`, which matches any non-word character. In order to fix this, you can use the following regular expression:

```
\b((?i)kohls(?-i))\b
```

The `\b` (before and after the word you want to match) is used to assert the position at a word boundary. See how this work on that website now:

[image]

If you still have questions, look at the explanation of the regular expression provided by that website. It is worth looking.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for the above example. It doesn't seem to work in some cases though. For example, if I want to pull the word "Kohls" from the url www.Kohls&Michaels.com. What would it need to change to include?

Comment: The regex in my answer should also work for www.Kohls&Michaels.com. You can try it in the regex101.com website and you will see that it matches correctly. How exactly are you programming this? Maybe the problem is in your code, not in the regular expression itself.

Comment: My apologies. What I meant to say is that it doesn't return a match for www.KohlsAndMichaels.com - even when using regex101.com.

Answer (score 0):

The `\W` metacharacter is used to find [non-word characters](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp). So adding a [star operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) will match 0 or more of these non-word characters (like periods). Did you meant to add a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) instead?

```
\b(?i)kohls(?-i)\b
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace both `\W*` with `[\W,\.\-]*` etc.

Should be enough.